# WP ajax always returns 0 even when using die

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying to use ajax the WP way and I cannot get a response back. If I use ajax manually and include the url to a php file it works fine. But I want to use ajax in wp the "proper" way.

Here is what I have.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_data', 'get_data');
function get_data(){
   $group = $_GET['option_group'];
   $data_table = 'tablename';

   // Array to hold data
   $bigArray = array();
   // Variable to determine the select clause
   $query = "SELECT * FROM $data_table WHERE `group` = $group ";
   $datas = $wpdb->get_results($query);

   foreach($datas as $data) {
      array_push($bigArray, $data);
   }

   echo json_encode($bigArray);

   //Don't forget to always exit in the ajax function.
   die();
}
```

Then the request

```
jQuery('#new_service #service_option_group').on('change', function() {
    // Ajax query to fetch the results
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'get_data',    
            data: jQuery('#service_option_group').serialize()
        },
        success: function(result) {
            jQuery('#new_service #service_option_region').empty();

            // need to add the default option back in
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            var select = document.getElementById('service_option_region');
            option.text = 'Select an Option'
            option.value = -1;
            select.appendChild(option);

            // Append on the events
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                // create and append each element
                var option = document.createElement('option');

                option.text = result[i].title;
                option.value = result[i].id;

                var select = document.getElementById('service_option_region');
                select.appendChild(option);
            }
        },
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: Are you logged in when you make the AJAX call? Also try enabling WP_DEBUG and see if that sheds some light on the issue.

Comment: Yes its in the backend on custom options page.

Comment: Ok figured it out that I have to have this in functions.php I was unaware and assumed I could use this function in my wp options page file. So now I am having an issue getting each post value from the serialized form data. Seems that you can't use serialize using this method which kind of makes this an even longer approach to just manually using ajax.